# Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: .git directory is not found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am referring code from the link: https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/spring-boot-microservices-series. When I simply build the code, I get the below error.

Could you please update on any pointers?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.3:revision (default) on project config-server: .git directory is not found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.3:revision (default) on project config-server: .git directory is not found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: .git directory is not found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml
```

**List from the derectories?**

```
$ ls -ltra
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 users-microservice/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 recommendation-microservice/
-rw-r--r-- 1 e081155 1049089  2538 Nov 11  2016 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 e081155 1049089  4180 Nov 11  2016 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 movies-ui/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 movie-microservice/
-rw-r--r-- 1 e081155 1049089 11358 Nov 11  2016 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 hystrix-dashboard/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 docker/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 discovery-microservice/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 consul-microservice/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 config-microservice/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Nov 11  2016 api-gateway-microservice/
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Aug 24 01:13 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 e081155 1049089     0 Aug 24 01:15 ./
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `config-server` has the maven plugin `git-commit-id-plugin` defined in it's `pom.xml`. I don't know exactly what it does but I assume by the name it tries to perform some git commands.

Edit: Your project folder does not seem to contain a `.git` folder, which means that it's not a git repository, which causes the maven plugin to fail.

Clone the linked repo with `git clone https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/spring-boot-microservices-series.git`

Or initialize a new repo in the project folder using `git init`.

Comment: I'll try. Did you just clone the entire github repo?

Comment: `./mvnw clean package -DskipTests=true` works for me. This is where your error occurs?

Comment: Still building fine.

Comment: Yes but that shouldn't matter. Does your root folder contain the `.git` directory?

Comment: I updated my post.. Not sure I clone the project again and its working fine. I am sure this can be reproduced the way I said. Could you guide me here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993175/org-springframework-web-client-resourceaccessexception-i-o-error-on-get-request

Comment: I give it a look. Mark my answer as correct please. I updated it.

Comment: Even though .git not present still its working now, so crazy