# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for in Microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am developing microservices code from the link : https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/spring-boot-microservices-series. In this code base, I was successfully able to start the services like `"config-service"`, `"service-registry"`, `"shoppingcart-ui"`, `"zipkin-server"` etc, but when I tried to start the `"inventory-service"`, I got the below error.

**Error below for reference:-**

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/inventory-service": Connect to localhost:8200 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8200 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:332) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.lambda$doRead$1(VaultTemplate.java:320) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doWithSession(VaultTemplate.java:307) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doRead(VaultTemplate.java:317) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.read(VaultTemplate.java:212) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.doGetSecrets(SecretLeaseContainer.java:545) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.start(SecretLeaseContainer.java:357) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.addRequestedSecret(SecretLeaseContainer.java:316) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.loadProperties(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:147) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.<init>(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:133) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.createVaultPropertySource(LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.java:151) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.createVaultPropertySource(LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.java:88) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.doCreatePropertySources(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:170) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.createCompositePropertySource(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:145) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.locate(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:116) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:636) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:376) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:328) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sivalabs.inventoryservice.InventoryServiceApplication.main(InventoryServiceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
```

**I updated parent pom version to 2.0.4.RELEASE.**

[image]

Comment: Did you run all the docker commands listed on the github page?

Comment: I am running code locally. Do we need to tweak anything to run code without docker ?

Comment: Not according to the readme. But it obviously fails to connect to port `8200` which is the vault. Is vault up and running?

Comment: Are you able to run using docker ?

Comment: If you have no local vault running use `docker-compose up -d setup-vault` atleast. Your error is indicating that the connection to vault fails.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure vault is running as per microservice configuration:

```
# Vault
spring.cloud.vault.host=localhost
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
```

Usually, when the service is not running on a port, you can `Connection refused` error.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. Vault service is up and running and can be accessed with vault CLI or culr from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL that the Vault is running on. It's displayed on the teminal. If you're running in developer mode it is http://127.0.0.1:8200 and not https://localhost:8200